# Perforce client error: Connection refused

Tags: server, perforce, p4v, p4a

So I had been successfully running Perforce on a dedicated Ubuntu 20.04 LTS cloud server for many months. I recently however moved to a different house and now I cannot connect to the server anymore through P4Admin and P4V, and neither can the other users. I've been getting this error in P4Admin:

Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to 81.169.151.191:1666 failed.
connect: 81.169.151.191:1666: WSAECONNREFUSED

And get this error when connected to the server in Putty as root user:

p4 info
Perforce client error:
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to 81.169.151.191:1666 failed.
connect: 81.169.151.191:1666: Connection refused

Has something gone wrong with the server? Anything I can do to restore the connection? My apologies in advance, I'm not an advanced user and have just been trying whatever the tutorials suggest.

Comment: When you're remotely logged into the server via Putty, can you do `p4 -p 1666 info`?

Comment: This gives me the same error I'm affraid:
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to 1666 failed.
        connect: 127.0.0.1:1666: Connection refused

Comment: Are you positive the server is actually running on that machine?  What happens if you run, say, `p4d -p 1666`?  (If it's running already, it should give you a "port in use" error.)

Comment: That actually did a thing! It then said Perforce Server starting. I'm not sure what happened, it seems like it shut down for some unknown reason. Maybe due to inactivity? Thanks so much!

Comment: Then perforce server info shows error messages:

2022/08/24 14:53:13 pid 6699 User2@User2_ElComputero_7732 96.22.86.140 [Unity/v80] 'user-logout'

--- failed authentication check

Then it disconnects all users including me...

Comment: I don't think the "failed authentication check" has anything to do with the server shutting down.  Do you have the server set up so that p4d runs on boot (so that the Perforce server will start itself any time the virtual server restarts)?

Comment: I don't remember configuring that. The server is now up and running again. I got a recommendation to look into IP filtering to block any unwanted traffic. But I'm still unsure if that's what's been causing the disconnects.